# Is there a \flushbottom-like command that may also decrease vertical spacing?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

I am currently working on my thesis, which (hopefully) will once be finished and will then have to be printed. I would like the bottom lines of all pages to be aligned, like `\flushbottom` does.

The `\flushbottom`-command however seems to be capable only of *increasing* vertical spacing, which works wonderfully most of the time, unless a page contains a lot of enumerations, as tends to happen with a lot of proofs by cases. There, the command goes slightly haywire, creating enormous vertical whitespace between items.

So, I am wondering: is there a command or package that does the same thing that `\flushbottom` does, but that might also *decrease* vertical spacing whenever that is necessary?

Answer (score 4):

flushbottom doesn't increase or decrease spacing, it just doesn't add the stretch space at the bottom of the page that is added by `\flushbottom`.

Whether the white space stretches or shrinks is a property of each space, which can have `plus` (stretch) and `minus` (shrink) components.

Comment: Purely out of technical interest (as my practical problem was caused by align-environments demanding new pages, which is solved by allowing `align`-environments to have page-breaks):

Adding the `\flushbottom` command _does_ increase vertical whitespaces between items, relative to not adding the `flushbottom` command. The only way I can sensibly interpret your answer is by reading `\raggedbottom` instead of `\flushbottom` as the final word of your first paragraph. Does that mean that LaTeX stretches within a page by default, but \raggedbottom overrides this by adding stretches at page-bottoms?